# Google Tag Manager .NET event tracking?

Tags: c#, google-tag-manager

I've found a .NET library to query/write information to Google Tag Manager here:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/tagmanager/v1/csharp/latest/annotated.html

The javascript version goes like this:
Google Tag Manager takes a GTM-id and you push events to a dataLayer array. I'm looking for the same thing, but in .NET, but can't seem to find it.

Does such a thing exist in .NET or does it seem i just can't find it in the documentation?

I'm asking this, because we'd like to send some information to GTM which should not be visible with google chrome's inspect element function or console. This information is private to our company (and GTM). We cannot allow the risk for people to inspect the page source and find revenue values per product (for example)

Comment: ***gtag.js*** for track exceptions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/exceptions?hl=es-419